# Mockito return false

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I write a simple test on mokito.

```
public class ContactServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private ServiceClient client;

    @Mock
    private ContactService contactService;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        client = mock(ServiceClient.class);
        contactService = mock(ContactService.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_sendEmailContact() {
        ContactDTO cDto = new ContactDTO();
        cDto.setTitle("Mr");
        cDto.setFirstName("Pritam");
        cDto.setLastName("Mohapatra");
        cDto.setTelephone("9439586575");
        cDto.setEmail("pritam.pritam176@gmail.com");
        cDto.setBetreff("test value");
        cDto.setAnfrage("test value");
        when(client.postToService("customer/sendEmailContact", cDto, Boolean.class)).thenReturn(true);
        Assert.assertEquals(true, contactService.sendEmailContact(cDto));
    }

}
```

- but when fail msg is expected true return false what I miss.

Comment: Unrelated but you don't need to use both the @Mock annotation and assign the mock in your before method. Also you're not injecting the mocks into the ContactDTO?

Comment: Can you post also code for `ServiceClient` and `ContactService` or at least relevant methods and constructors? Also is `ContactService` something that uses `ServiceClient `? If yes then it should not be mock but real class and you should set `ServiceClient` which is mock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using `ServiceClient` in `ContactService` to actually send email contact. However you defined your `ContactService` to be mock so you are actually testing mock instead of real class.

**Option 1** prefered option if `ContactService` does not need to be mock:

1. Define `ContactService` as real class with `new ClientService`
2. Inject somehow mock of `ServiceClient` (via constructor or setter, you did not posted code so I do not know how they work together)
3. Since `ContactService` is now real instance with injected mock of `ServiceClient` it will go to real method and invoke `client.postToService` which will return `true` as you defined.

**Option 2** would be to do `thenCallRealMethod` on `ContactService` mock if you really need it to be mock (but I do not see why it should be mock). Something like:

```
when(contactService.sendEmailContact(cDto)).thenCallRealMethod();
```

Comment: yes I forget to inject the mock object to ContactService